# To be completely removed in the Media Query. How can I do so?

Tags: html, css

Be completely removed in the Media Query. How can I do so?

I have the following CSS:

```
    #container {
        width: 50%;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With media queries you can override the CSS when the device has a certain width.

So:

```
#container {
    width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #container {
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

But **you can't delete a CSS rule**, in fact every element has all the CSS values already setted by default and by the browser and you **just override** some of them, if you ispect an element and go under "computed" tab of the developer tools you can see all the CSS atributes.

Those are the CSS file used by the browser (called user agent stylesheet):

- Firefox (Gecko): https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/res/html.css.
- Chrome/Safari (WebKit): http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css

  - Chrome (Blink): https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/css/html.css
- Internet Explorer (Trident), older versions: http://www.iecss.com/

However **you can reset to default** a CSS value using `value:initial;` so `width:initial;` but if you know the CSS default value (whitch is visible [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)) you can specific it (In this case `width:auto;`).

Read this to know more about media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: ,basso99 I'm aware you can override it but is there a way to just make it as if `width` never existed? Like remove it.

Comment: That is essentially what width auto does.

Answer (score 0):

the initial value of the width property is auto, which means that if you set the width to auto, it would be like no other width rule exists.

```
#container {
    width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #container {
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Also, since it is better to write Mobile-first css, I would remove completely the #container selector and add the following media query

```
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    #container {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value *initial*. More info about it here: [CSS Initial/Inherit](https://css-tricks.com/getting-acquainted-with-initial/)

```
 #container {
    width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #container {
        width: initial;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is that you want to completely remove the width via media queries of your container correct? If so, simply add '0' to that ID for your width.  If you prefer, you can put '0px' or '0%' but that really isn't needed.  If this does not work, try adding '!important' to your media query like below.

```
#container {
        width: 50%;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #container {
        width: 0;
    }
}
```

or

```
#container {
        width: 50%;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #container {
        width: 0 !important;
    }
}
```